# Ubuntu 21.10 Resolution Problem

Tags: display-resolution, 21.10

So I recently upgraded from Windows 10 to Ubuntu and decided to give Linux a try. For some odd reason when I installed it the resolution was stuck on 1024x768. I did so much research and most of them were the 'xrandr' trick which does not work for me at all. Also it shows that I'm XWAYLAND0 which I saw people say it doesn't work on xrandr. Can anyone please help?

Note: My PC is fairly old but it did run Windows 10 with no problems and no resolution problems. I only have this problem on the Ubuntu and the Ubuntu distro alone.

Comment: Details are lacking. What is the "xrandr trick"? Always provide clear reproducible details, so the exact commands you have used should be included in your question, especially if your actions were harmful and need to be reversed. We also have no idea what hardware you are using. What is the GPU model?  If you are using Wayland than anything you do in xrandr is irrelevant *while you are using Wayland*.  You can log off and there should be an option to log in with x.org instead of Wayland. X.org is more likely to be compatible with a wider range of hardware. I suggest that you do that first.

Comment: What is the terminal output of `env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` please?

Comment: What I mean by the 'xrandr trick' is the 

xrandr --newmode and xrandr --addmode.

And I did what you said. I went on Xorg and it did add the resolutions but when I did the xrandr commands and added the resolutions my screen completely blacks out and I can't do anything but restart the computer. I tried editing the xorg.conf and tried selecting the resolutions but still didn't work. Resolutions are available but the problem is that it doesn't change at all. I select 1920x1080 but it doesn't change from 1024x768.

Comment: You have not answered multiple fact finding questions. Please read comments carefully and answer all questions. We ask because we need this info to make any further suggestions. Use the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1380650/edit) link to update your question. You have unlimited space and unlimited time, so please take your time and be thorough before responding.  After you have edited your question with complete information, make a comment indicating that the question is updated and tag me @nmath or I might miss it. Please don't respond until you have added all requested info.